# Increasing a specific landcover class by a % in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is it possible to increase a specific landcover class by a % figure in ArcGIS. For example, I am making a flood model in HEC-HMS and how rainfall events are affected by an increase in urban landcover, the gov projections for the major city in my catchment area states an increase in population by 13%.

Would there be a way to increase the urban landcover by 13%?

Comment: Population increase doesn't necessarily mean an equal increase in urban landcover. This also strongly depends on social and economical factors, as well as steering by the government. Do poor people move to the city? - they tend to live in cramped quarters, so the landcover will increase less. Do wealthy people move? - Hello suburbia! Does the government promote the increase of building density within the city, or maybe the "reusage" of e.g. industrial wasteland? So, if this shall be slightly scientifically, I suggest you do some research first.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to iteratively buffer a polygon to increase its size, but that is meaningless in the context of your task.

Comment: With simple assumption, that population density remains the same over future urban areas, it makes sense. Solution depends on a source of land use layer. Is it a raster or feature class?